# Application with same functionalities for architecture performance testing

Tags: architecture, microservices, monolithic

I am writing a thesis for my University where I am going to compare two architectures: monolithic vs microservices.

I am wondering if there is a free licensed example of application written in Java/Spring which has the same functionalities, but created in two different architectures? I was looking for such example, but couldn't find it. I don't want to spend time on writing a code, because goal of my thesis is to perform a lot of performance testing and work on results. Do you know about something like it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of example apps around that, but my advice would be to create them yourself, it'll be a journey that you help you to learn lots of things around those 2 architectural models.

On top of that, you still need to know pretty much all the details of each implementation in order to create an accurate performance assessment.